How I can find crash log from iOS device and upload to my own server from the App?
I am working on an iOS app and part of the work is that collecting the crash log from the devoice if happened and then upload it to my own server. I don't know if that is possible in iOS, Please suggest how I can do it ?
I don't want to use crashyltics

You can have the user email you the crash log. Apple's documentation says the steps which work for iOS, iPadOS, watchOS, and tvOS apps are:

Open the Analytics & Improvements section of Settings on the device.
See Share analytics, diagnostics, and usage information with Apple.

Tap Analytics Data.

Locate the log for your app. The log name starts with
 for crash reports, or
JetsamEvent for high-memory use crashes.

Select the desired log.

Tap the Share icon, and select Mail to send the crash report as a
mail attachment.


